# How to re install rom on blank htc desire?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, rooting, htc-desire

I have installed rom in the memory card of my htc desire bt unfortunately i have lost my memory card. Now my ph is not working; everytime it just shows "HTC" and then restart. Can anyone please suggest me stable rom with proper configurations?

I am using HTC Desire A8181.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [This Link](http://techmell.net/android-tips/root-htc-desire-how-to/) depending on your HTC, your phone model is HTC Bravo you can download your roms [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=809328) your

**Edit: Official RUU 3.14 Desire Gingerbread---[v1.2/1st/August/2012] this is best rom it also give you more then 100mb free space. i used it for my device too**

Comment: "This Link" is broken

Answer (score -2):

You can download a ROM [from TechTuple](http://www.techtuple.com/919/list-of-best-custom-rom-for-htc-desire-bravo/), copy it to your *HTC Desire A8181*, and flash it via CWM recovery.